# Which language is used for programming the google's Translator Frontend?

Tags: frontend, google-translate

This is a simple question:
I would like to know, in which language is Google Translator Frontend programmed in?
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front-end? This: http://translate.google.com/ ? Javascript (AJAX)/HTML/Css (you can look at the source code)

At each keypressed they will send a GET request (callback in JSON) which will contain the language, the char you typed in order to update the UI.

Example: Input (English): Do you like sushi? Output (Spanish): ¿Te gusta el sushi ?

```
         [[["¿Te gusta el sushi ?","Do you like sushi?","",""]],,"en",,
[["¿Te gusta el",[5],1,0,905,0,4,0],["sushi",[6],1,0,508,4,5,0],
["?",[7],0,0,566,5,6,0]],[["Do you like",5,
        [["¿Te gusta el",905,1,0],["Qué te gusta",0,1,0]],
[[0,11]],"Do you like sushi?"],["sushi",6,
        [["sushi",508,1,0],["el sushi",36,1,0],["de sushi",0,1,0],
["sushi de",0,1,0]],[[12,17]],""],
        ["?",7,[["?",566,0,0]],[[17,18]],""]],,,[["en"]],30]
```

Comment: Its the Ajax technology what I was looking for,
That's answer my question, Thanks!